# How to sum value of radio button and checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, sum

I have a code already working which calculates the sum of the radio buttons. I changed my mind in one of the radio button group and decided to make it a checkbox. When I tick items on the checkbox, the sum returns **NaN**. What would I add/change in my jquery in order for it to recognize the checkbox value?

Here's my code:

JQuery

```js
 < script type = "text/javascript" >
   function calcscore() {
     $(".calc:checked").each(function() {
       score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
     });
     $('#price').text(score.toFixed(2));
     $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
   }
 $().ready(function() {
   $(".calc").change(function() {
     calcscore()
   });
 }); 
< /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1" />
    
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="rad1" value="100">
</li>


<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="200" />
    
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="check1" value="200">
</li>

<p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span>
</p>
```

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: I'm not an php expert but what do you have in your radio buttons value property? Integers?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't work because it contains PHP scripts. Could you strip it to minimum working example?

Comment: yes. it's a user inputted text in the front end. it serves as the price for the item

Comment: @Martin sorry bout that. ill simplify it

Comment: What do you need the hidden inputs for? Please move the value of the "rad1" input to the "rad1" radio

Comment: I need the hidden input to hook another value into the radio button @FabianH.

Answer (score 1):

This code code should answer your question:

```js
function calcscore() {
 score = 0;
 $(".calc:checked").each(function () {
  score += Number($(this).val());
 });
 $("#price").text(score.toFixed(2));
 $("#sum").val(score)
}
$().ready(function () {
 $(".calc").change(function () {
  calcscore()
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1" value="100" />
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="200" />
  </label>
</li>
<input type="hidden" name="sum" id="sum" value="0">
<p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span>
</p>
```

Comment: thank you for the response guys! got the code up and ready already!

Answer (score 0):

for your markup and usecase as it stands now in the question.try this

```js
$('.calc').on('click', function() {

  var sum = 0;

  $('.calc:checked').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).parent().next().val())

  })

  $('#price').text(sum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1" />

  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="rad1" value="100">
</li>


<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="200" />

  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="check1" value="200">
</li>

<p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span>
</p>
```

try this,you dont need hidden fields for values.i removed them and used value property of checkbox.

```js
$('.calc').on('click', function() {

  var sum = 0;

  $('.calc:checked').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val())

  })

  $('#price').text(sum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="100" id="rad1" />

  </label>

</li>


<li>
  <label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="200" id="check1" value="200" />

  </label>

</li>

<p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span>
</p>
```